# Find the volume of the figures rotating around the y-axis and bounded by

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume of the figures rotating around the y-axis and bounded by: 
$$y=e^x+6$$
$$y=e^{2x}$$
$$x=0$$
Here's a chart (hopefully correctly):
[image]

What should happen next?
What is substitute into this formula?
$$V_y=\pi \int _a^b\:y^2dx$$

Comment: If you want to integrate with respect to $x$, use the method of Cylindrical Shells. If you want to use slicing, the integration will be with respect to $y$, amd you will need to solve for $x$ in terms of $y$. Also,  the integral will have to be broken into two parts, much more unpleasant.

Comment: And could you show this integral?

Comment: I have set it up, but have not evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simplest to use the Method of Cylindrical Shells. First let is see where the curves $y=e^{2x}$ and $y=e^x+6$ meet. Let $w=e^x$. We are solving $w^2-w-6=0$. The only positive root is $w=3$, giving $x=\ln 3$.

The "height" of the shell at $x$ is $e^x+6-e^{2x}$, and the radius is $x$. So the volume is
$$\int_0^{\ln 3} 2\pi x\left(e^x+6-e^{2x}\right)\,dx.\tag{1}$$
The integration is not too bad, one uses integration by parts.

**Remark:** We have given a very condensed "explanation" of the components of Expression (1). It may be sufficient if you have some experience in using the Method, but not otherwise.

Comment: You are welcome.  One can, as I mentioned earlier, do it by taking slices perpendicular to the $y$-axis, and integrating with respect to $y$. But we have to break up the integral at $y=7$, and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$. Doable, but more complicated.